# noCaptcha alternative

Tags: security, google-apps, captcha

[It's no secret](https://security.googleblog.com/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html), that CAPTCHA's no longer offer a reliable protection against automated attacks.

CAPTCHAs have become easy to solve for bots, but the distorted text is often very hard to read for users and can be an insurmountable obstacle (especially for those with disabilities).

As far as I can tell Google's noCaptcha is currently the only reliable piece of software for avoiding automated attacks, but it comes with obvious [privacy concerns](https://www.businessinsider.com/google-no-captcha-adtruth-privacy-research-2015-2?r=DE&IR=T) which makes it impossible for us to use.

Are there any alternatives to google's noCaptcha? Data protection is a huge factor, so we need some sort of control over which data is collected and where it is stored.

Comment: Although many types of text-distortion algorithms have been beaten by artificial intelligence, this doesn’t mean all of them have. If you want to try alternative ways to distort images for self-made captchas (runs on your own servers), look at [this forum post](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t10685-). If this has any chance of success, you probably need to vary 2 things on a continuous basis: The type of distortion you use (mix and match processing functions), and the amount of distortion you introduce (randomize function parameters so that you get unique results every time).

Comment: @AminDodin Thanks I'll look into that. While this would provide a more secure CAPTCHAs, it still doesn't solve the usability and accessibility concerns I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It doesn't address all aspects of your question, that's why I didn't post it as an answer.